# sqlloader with constraint NOT NULL in oracle table

Tags: oracle, csv, sql-loader

I'm entering values from a CSV file  to an Oracle table using a SQL*Loader script. In this table there are fields with `NOT NULL` constraints. In my CSV file the corresponding field is `""` and I would like put a blank string into the Oracle table when that happens.

This is my control file:

```
LOAD DATA
    infile 'F:\tar.csv'
    REPLACE
    INTO TABLE tar
    fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
    TRAILING NULLCOLS
    (IDTAR   ,
DATABACKUP   DATE "YYYY-MM-DD",
PAESE ,
R_ELEM  NULLIF (R_ELEM=BLANKS))
```

and this is the error in the log file:

ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("MY_SCHEMA"."TAR"."PAESE")

How can I avoid the error by supplying a different value?

Comment: What do you mean by a blank string? An empty string is the same as null in Oracle, so do you mean one or more whitespace characters? Including your table DDL and sample data from your CSV file would be helpful too.

Comment: An empty string is the same as null in Oracle .Ahh!!!
That's the point !!!

Comment: ["Oracle Database currently treats a character value with a length of zero as null. However, this may not continue to be true in future releases, and Oracle recommends that you do not treat empty strings the same as nulls."](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements005.htm#SQLRF30037)

Answer (score 1):

You can [apply an SQL operator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sutil/oracle-sql-loader-field-list-contents.html#GUID-83FF6EDC-C7F8-4F29-8994-59153BE31924), such as `NVL(:PAESE, 'XXX')`. Notice the colon before the reference to the field name. In situ:

```
LOAD DATA
  infile 'gian.csv'
  REPLACE
  INTO TABLE tar
  fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"'
  TRAILING NULLCOLS
  (
    IDTAR,
    DATABACKUP  DATE "YYYY-MM-DD",
    PAESE "NVL(:PAESE, 'XXX')",
    R_ELEM  NULLIF (R_ELEM=BLANKS)
  )
```

With a dummy table:

create table tar (
idtar number,
databackup date,
paese varchar2(10) not null,
r_elem varchar2(10)
);

and CSV, where the 3rd and 4th lines have trailing spaces for the `nullif()` clause:

```
1,2017-08-01,A,B
2,2017-08-02,C,
3,2017-08-03,,    
4,2017-08-04,"",
```

then running with that control file gets:

```
SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production on Fri Aug 4 19:39:23 2017

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 4
```

and the log says:

```
...
   Column Name                  Position   Len  Term Encl Datatype
------------------------------ ---------- ----- ---- ---- ---------------------
IDTAR                               FIRST     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
DATABACKUP                           NEXT     *   ,  O(") DATE YYYY-MM-DD
PAESE                                NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
    SQL string for column : "NVL(:PAESE, 'XXX')"
R_ELEM                               NEXT     *   ,  O(") CHARACTER
    NULL if R_ELEM = BLANKS


Table TAR:
  4 Rows successfully loaded.
  0 Rows not loaded due to data errors.
  0 Rows not loaded because all WHEN clauses were failed.
  0 Rows not loaded because all fields were null.
...
```

Querying the table shows all four rows were loaded:

```
set null "<null>"
select * from tar;

     IDTAR DATABACKU PAESE      R_ELEM    
---------- --------- ---------- ----------
         1 01-AUG-17 A          B         
         2 02-AUG-17 C          <null>    
         3 03-AUG-17 XXX        <null>    
         4 04-AUG-17 XXX        <null>
```

Obviously replace `'XXX'` with the actual default string you want to use. You said 'a blank string', so you could use `"NVL(:PAESE, ' ')"` to insert a single space character for instance. You can't use an *empty* string though, as that is the same as null as far as Oracle is concerned.

Comment: what if the third column cannot accept null values? like if encountered col3=null, then the entire row will not be recorded. how can this be done?